# EE Brightbox Router2 won't switch on at all; no lights showing

Tags: networking, router, hardware-failure

I have an EE Brightbox Router2 which suddenly dropped the connection. On inspection I notice there were no lights on the router at all. I tried removing the power adapter, waiting ten seconds then plugging it back in again, but this doesn't work. I also tried pressing the reset switch.

Is there any end-user maintenance I could perform which is likely to get the router running again at all?

Comment: Have you tried plugging it into a known working (tested with a lamp) power socket?

Comment: Switching the power socket! Of course! And here's me ready to assume it's hackers bricking it remotely! **Hits self on head and goes off to try another power socket...** Update: narp, not the power socket.

Comment: Also check for tripped fuses - assuming you have a newish fuse box ... otherwise check for blown fuses.

Comment: The rest of the power is working, so it's not the fuses... Unless; does the Brightbox2 have a fuse?

Comment: Likely a dead router then. Phone EE and ask for a replacement.

Comment: I'll just pop into town in a bit. Thought that would probably be the case but thought there might be something else I could try. Wasn't sure if there were any user-serviceable parts. Don't really want to be using my phone as a hotspot much longer than necessary :/.